# .svg displays as a broken image in Chrome, Safari and Opera. Locally

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, adobe-brackets

Here's the code:

```
<img src="../img/triangle.svg" id="triangle" alt="Arrow Down">
```

What's strange is that I'm using Brackets and in its Live Preview (some version of Chrome, opens as a different application) the svg displays correctly. But when I open it in any other browser, including the normal Chrome it doesn't display and reverts to the alt attribute.

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

wrong directory.

Comment: Then your path is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your path is wrong. Try something different like `/img/triangle.svg` (the leading slash means the path is relative to your website root).